# What are the different processor registers used by the VS C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

What are the different registers used by the C++ compiler in a program? What is the difference between SP and FP? If possible please point me to some detailed reference docs. Curious to know the underlying things happening in a compiler. Is it possible to view these registers during the execution of a program in Visual Studio.
Appreciate your time and help.
Thanks in advance,
Light

Comment: Here's the detailed doc: http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253665.pdf. You asked for it.

Comment: This is completely platform- and compiler-dependant, so it cannot be answered in general.

Comment: strager, he's obviously referring to IA-32.

Comment: This is not only compiler-dependent (I understand you're referring to VS), it is also dependent on the targeted platform. It might, however, also depend on compiler settings and compiler version.

Comment: Definitely depends on compiler settings. X64 registers are not used in x86 mode, for instance. And the Frame Pointer Optimimalization setting determines whether the Frame Pointer register is used as a generic register.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask compiler to output the assembler code it generates from your sources, it's /FA and /Fa compiler command line arguments you're looking for: [msdn link to /FA compiler arg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6(VS.80).aspx).
In run-time, when you're running your program under debugger, you can open a "registers" window, and see how the values change during the execution - it can be very useful sometimes. Here's how you do it: [msdn doc about "registers" window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62680774(VS.80).aspx)
If you're going for more serious debugging, I'd recommend investing some time learning to use this: [debugging tools for windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) instead of just using the built-in VS debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on the hardware you are programming to.  Each processor family has it's own architecture and therefore it's own register.

Here is a good [reference on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language) for the Intel chips.

Answer (score 0):

A stack pointer (SP) points into memory and is used to store function call-related data such as function parameters, return address and local variables. This data forms a stack frame for each function call and is pointed at by frame pointer (FP). Each thread of execution has a stack pointer. Each function call has its own stack frame and frame pointer. A stack backtrace works its way back through the stack frames of each nested function call allowing you to see the parameters and local data of each function call.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_pointer#Structure

The above link contains more description and a picture.

Answer (score -2):

There is debugger fou such questions.